# How to implement a timer for regular events?

Tags: c#, wpf, events, timer

I would like to implement some timers into my application.
My goal is to provide an easy way to execute some function every x seconds/minutes so I thought about implementing a 1 sec, 5 sec and 15 seconds timer.
The first thing i would like to update every 1 second is the built in clock (don't know if there is any other solution in c#, used this method in c++)
Another use would be e.g. a sync function etc. which shall be executed every xx seconds.

My question is if there are any useful tutorials on this topic? It is the first time that I would like to implement such an timer system into one of my applications and I do not know if there are any things I have to keep in mind.

Thank you in advance for any answer :)

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are various types of Timer classes you can use.

In WPF, if this is for updating something user interface related, you would typically use a [`DispatcherTimer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx).

You could also use a [`System.Timers.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx) or [`System.Threading.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx), but realize that this will fire on a background thread, and not on the main user interface thread.  This is often beneficial (you don't wait or block your UI if there is "work" happening in the Timer's `Tick` event or callback), but you also have to remember to marshal anything user interface related back to the UI thread.

Answer (score 1):

```
    // This timer runs on UI thread
    System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer timer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
    timer.Interval = System.TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
    timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
    timer.Start();

    void timer_Tick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Title = System.Windows.Input.Keyboard.FocusedElement.GetType().ToString();
    }
```